# Facing problem in putting color dots of relevant events on a single date

Tags: angular, nativescript, nativescript-angular, nativescript-telerik-ui, angular-nativescript

I am facing problem in showing dots of events on a single date. However, I managed to display event color as a square box. But I want to display it as a dot. The events are coming from the API. Any suggestions how can I overcome this problem?

When I click on a particular date, it retrieves the corresponding events from the API and shows the events on that particular date. The color is also coming from the API request. I just need to show the events with the additional dots with the relevant color from the API

Can Angular component be used in Nativescript app? Then I could have used angular component!

This is the html file of calendar component!

```
<StackLayout row="0">
        <RadCalendar [monthViewStyle]="monthViewStyle" [eventSource]="eventSource" [selectedDate]="defaultDate"
            (dateSelected)="onDateSelected($event)" row="0" (navigatedToDate)="onNavigatedToDate($event)"></RadCalendar>
    </StackLayout>
```

[image]

```
bindEventsInCalender(date: string) {

    this._calendarApiService.getCalendarData(date).subscribe((data: any) => {

      var listCal = data;
      let event: CalendarEvent;
      this.calendarEvents = [];
      let events: Array<CalendarEvent> = new Array<CalendarEvent>();
      for (let i = 0; i < listCal.length; i++) {
        // console.log(new Date(listCal[i].date));

        event = new CalendarEvent(
          listCal[i].title,
          new Date(listCal[i].date),
          new Date(listCal[i].date),
          false,
          new Color(listCal[i].colour)
        );

        // this.calendarEvents.push(new CalendarClass(new Date(listCal[i].date), listCal[i].colour, listCal[i].title, listCal[i].statusid, listCal[i].id));
        this.updateCalendarEvent(listCal[i]);

        events.push(event);
      }
      // console.log(this.calendarEvents);

      if (this._events_mirror.length > 0) {
        this._events_mirror.forEach(element => {
          events.push(element);
        });
      }
      this._events = events;
      if (this.appRunFirstTime) {
        this.appRunFirstTime = false;
        this.defaultDate = new Date();
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: With Android you could define your [custom renderer](https://www.telerik.com/forums/radcalendar-events-eventrenderer-(custom-painting-of-events)) to add more dots, not sure about iOS.

Comment: But I am using Nativescript! How will I add dots in Nativescript? @Manoj

Comment: I meant you have to write native code in your NativeScript application, override the event renderer that is used by the underlaying nativeView of RadCalendar.

Comment: @Manoj Do you have any resources which have dots of events on a single date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](https://discourse.nativescript.org/t/extending-eventrenderer-of-radcalendar-throws-convertion-error/4315/5) I have an example for implementing custom event renderer for {N} Android. You will have to extend the base class `com.telerik.widget.calendar.events.EventRenderer` and use the `renderEvents` method to draw anything within the calendar cell. The example demonstrates how you can draw a circle instead of default rectangular for denoting events. You may even add more dots with the paint apis.

Comment: Thanks for sharing! My project is based on nativescript-angular! Will your code work there too?

Comment: Will I use https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-tsc&id=GxU36j&_ga=2.78645021.822254380.1554183473-1553618228.1552887509 or the other codes on link you gave? My project is based on nativescript-angular @Manoj

Comment: Angular is just a flavour, end of the all your code is just JavaScript. Yes it works.